# Can I make a script to open terminal and run .py?

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I have a simple python script I can run through terminal. Is there a way to put a shortcut on my mac desktop to open terminal and run like "cd ~/Desktop/script.py"? I have tried automator but i couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a file called `anyname.command` with `python ~/Desktop/script.py` in it. Then make it executable by running `chmod 555 ~/Desktop/anyname.command` in terminal.  Then when you double-click on `anyname.command` it should run the python script.

Comment: Thanks, but when i double click I get an error that i don't have permissions but when i get info I have read and write on. Please help.   EDIT- My mistake i forgot to make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

Automator would be your best bet actually, creating Macintosh .app bundles by hand can be annoying.

It's been a long time since I've used automator, but here goes, use the Run Shell Script command from Terminal, and make the script be `python ~/Desktop/script.py` or maybe use the full path like `python /Users/<username>/Desktop/script.py`

P.S. `cd ~/Desktop/script.py` doesn't do what you think it does, you want `python ~/Desktop/script.py`

Answer (score -1):

you have to create a samplename.sh file and put the below line and run it ./samplename.sh

~/Desktop/script.py

create symbolic link to that .sh file and place it on desktop.

Comment: How would that help with running it from a desktop icon? You can run the `script.py` directly the same way, not from the desktop though.